# Proof that magnetic Bloch waves are almost periodic in the reciprocal index

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, crystals

I would like to prove that the magnetic Bloch waves change by a phase factor if you shift their crystal momentum by a reciprocal lattice vector. That is, if $u_{n,\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$ is a Bloch wave and $\mathbf{c}$ is a basis vector of the reciprocal lattice, then there exists some $\phi \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
\begin{equation}
 u_{n, \mathbf{k} + \mathbf{c}}(\mathbf{r}) = e^{i \phi} u_{n, \mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}).
\end{equation}

I am mostly interested in the situation in two dimensions. So let us consider an electron constrained to move in the $xy$-plane, subject to a homogeneous magnetic field along the $z$-direction.
Let $\mathbf{a}=(a,0)$ and $\mathbf{b}=(0,b)$ be the basis vectors of the Bravais lattice. So the electron is also subject to an $\mathbf{a},\mathbf{b}$ periodic potential.

Let us denote the magnetic translation operators along $\mathbf{a}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ by $\hat{T}_{a}$ and $\hat{T}_{b}$. Suppose that $\hat{T}_{\mathbf{a}}$ and $\hat{T}_{\mathbf{b}}$ commute.

I have a proof that, given any function $\psi$, that is a simultaneous eigenvector of the magnetic translation operators $\hat{T}_{a}$ and $\hat{T}_{b}$, with eigenvalues $e^{i k_{x}}$ and $e^{i k_{y}}$ respectively, I can decompose $\psi$ as
\begin{equation}
 \psi( \mathbf{r}) = e^{i \mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}} u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}).
\end{equation}
Here, $\mathbf{k} = (k_{x},k_{y})$, and $u_{k}$ is the magnetic Bloch wave, which satisfies
\begin{align}
 u_{\mathbf{k}}(x+a,y) &= e^{-\frac{i}{2 l_{B}^{2}} ay} u_{\mathbf{k}}(x,y), \\
 u_{\mathbf{k}}(x,y + b) &= e^{\frac{i}{2 l_{B}^{2}} bx} u_{\mathbf{k}}(x,y).
\end{align}

Now here is my attempt to prove the periodicity of $u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$ in $\mathbf{k}$.

We can decompose $u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r})$ as
\begin{equation}
 u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{\mathbf{j}} c_{\mathbf{j}} e^{i \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{r}}.
\end{equation}
We now compute, on the one hand
\begin{align}
 e^{-\frac{i}{2l_{B}^{2}} ay} \sum_{\mathbf{j}} c_{\mathbf{j}} e^{i \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{r}} &= e^{-\frac{i}{2l_{B}^{2}} ay } u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) \\
&= u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r} + \mathbf{a}) \\
&= \sum_{\mathbf{j}} c_{\mathbf{j}} e^{i \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{a}} e^{i \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{r}}.
\end{align}
And on the other hand we have
\begin{align}
 e^{-\frac{i}{2l_{B}^{2}} ay} \sum_{\mathbf{j}} c_{\mathbf{j}} e^{i \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{r}} &= \sum_{\mathbf{j}} c_{\mathbf{j}} e^{i (j_{x} x +(j_{y} - \frac{a}{2l_{B}^{2}})y)}  \\
&= \sum_{\mathbf{j}} c_{\mathbf{j} + \frac{a}{2l_{B}^{2}} \hat{y}} e^{i \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{r}}.
\end{align}
Since plane waves with different wave vectors are linearly independent we may conclude that
\begin{equation}
 c_{\mathbf{j}+ \frac{a}{2l_{B}^{2}} \hat{y}} = c_{\mathbf{j}} e^{i \mathbf{j} \cdot \mathbf{a}}.
\end{equation}

And at this point I am kind of lost on what to do.

I though it might be instructive to look at the case that $B=0$, which would be equivalent to $l_{B} \rightarrow \infty$, then we would have
\begin{equation}
 c_{\mathbf{j}} = e^{i \mathbf{j} \cdot{a}} c_{\mathbf{j}},
\end{equation}
which would restrict $\mathbf{j}$ to the reciprocal lattice, but even then I would not know how to get the result I'm after.

I saw the formula
\begin{equation}
 \psi_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = \sum_{\mathbf{j}} c_{\mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k}} e^{i(\mathbf{j} + \mathbf{k}) \cdot \mathbf{r}},
\end{equation}
somewhere, without proof. I think I could probably complete the proof using this formula and the fact that
\begin{equation}
 u_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}) = e^{-i\mathbf{k}\cdot\mathbf{r}} \psi_{\mathbf{k}}(\mathbf{r}).
\end{equation}
But I have not been able to find a convincing proof of this either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are very close. Just note that $\sum_{\bf j}{c_{\bf j}}e^{i{\bf j}\cdot{\bf r}} = \sum_{\bf j}{c_{{\bf j}+{\bf c}}}e^{i({\bf j}+{\bf c})\cdot{\bf r}}$ if $\bf c$ is a (basis) vector of the reciprocal lattice, simply because ${\bf j}+{\bf c}$ runs over the same set as $\bf j$.